# WPF Drag and Drop Time Selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm just moving to WPF with a background in C# and MVC.  I am working on an hours worked application, we have to capture every 15 minute period of time that a person has worked within a 24 hour day.

I want to have a visual that looks like a grid where the user can click + drag in blocks of time. On the model I would want to represent this as a byte array for each day.

I'm hoping to get something that looks like the below.

[image: Hours Worked]

Is there a control I can use to do this?

If there isn't a control that does this how could I achieve the result?

Comment: If you have a fixed number of columns, you could do this with a [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid). You'll still need some kind of custom control for the ItemsTemplate to represent two 15-minute increments per column, and then set those to allow dragging.

Comment: @NextInLine thank you for pointing me in that direction.  I've managed to create a DataGrid and used a template to represent the quarter hours in TextBlocks but I have no idea where to start looking to allow dragging horizontally and not vertically.

Comment: Not sure if you want TextBlocks instead of something derived from Control; in any case, there is an AllowDrop property and DragEnter, DragLeave, DragOver, and Drop events. You hook those up in the TextBlocks or Controls (not the DataGrid). The challenge is to get where you are in the DataGrid; hopefully the DataContext in each cell will tell you.